# How to fix onesignal in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, onesignal, ionic-native

I have a problem with the onesignal in ionic 3
first I create a new project and when I add the onesignal plugin, I cannot build the app.

same as this steps:

```
ionic start myApp blank
ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin
npm install --save @ionic-native/onesignal
ionic cordova build --release --prod android
```

What should l do?

-- my command after step 4 in images

[image1](https://pasteboard.co/HuPD9os.jpg) -
[image2](https://pasteboard.co/HuPDFTU.jpg)

Comment: check what version of support library is installed in android sdk manager

Comment: [link](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-setup) go through this link and follow steps. i have successfully implement Onesignal in my App and its working well.

Comment: It's not working for me, I only install onesignal and then cannnot get output apk from app